# Difficulty at Solving Second Order PDE with D' Alembert Method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, problem-solving, initial-value-problems

Given the 2nd order linear PDE

\begin{align} 
u_{tt}&=\frac{1}{9}u_{xx}, & &t>0,\ x \in \mathbb{R}  \tag 1 \\
u(x,0)&=\frac{1}{x^2+9},&& x \in \mathbb{R} \tag 2\\
u_t&(x,0)=0, && x \in \mathbb{R} \tag 3\\
\lim_{|x|\to+\infty} u(x,t)&=\lim_{|x|\to+\infty} u_t(x,t)=0,&& t\geq0 \tag4
\end{align}

***Solution***
Let $c=\frac{1}{3}$
We calculate the discriminant
$$D=4c^2>0$$
So it is hyperbolic.

Now we have to find the characteristics
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{b\pm\sqrt{D}}{a}=\pm c$$
Thus,
\begin{align}
k_1&=x+ct\\
k_2&=x-ct
\end{align}

I used the following substitutions
\begin{align}
\xi&=x-ct\\
\eta&=x+ct
\end{align} and
$v(\xi(x, y), \eta(x,y)) = u(x, y)$.

We calculate the second-order partial derivatives and we have

- $u_{tt}=c^2 u_{\xi \xi}-2 c^2 u_{\xi \eta}+ c^2 u_{\eta \eta}$
- $u_{xx}=u_{\xi \xi}+2u_{\xi \eta}+u_{\eta \eta} $

So I got the canonical form
$$c^2 u_{\xi \xi}-2 c^2 u_{\xi \eta}+ c^2 u_{\eta \eta}= c^2(u_{\xi \xi}+2u_{\xi \eta}+u_{\eta \eta})$$

So,$4u_{\xi \eta}=0\tag 5$ then we integrate with $(5)$ with respect of $\eta$ and then we integrate  the result  with respect of $\xi$ and we will have
$$u(\xi,\eta)=f(\xi)+g(\eta)\Leftrightarrow u(x,t)=f(t-cx)+g(t+cx) \tag 6$$
where $f,g$ arbitrary functions.

We will follow the D'Alembert Method to Solve the problem for the following initial conditions

\begin{align} 
u(x,0)&=\varphi(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+9},&& x \in \mathbb{R} \\
u_t(x,0)&=h(x)=0, && x \in \mathbb{R} \\
\lim_{|x|\to+\infty} u(x,t)&=\lim_{|x|\to+\infty} u_t(x,t)=0,&& t\geq0 
\end{align}

- The solution, for $t=0$, could be written
  $$u(x,0)=f(x)+g(x) \Leftrightarrow f(x)+g(x)=\varphi(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+9} \tag 7$$

We differentiate $(6)$ with respect of $t$ and we get
$$u_t(x,t)= c(g'(x+ct)-f'(x-ct))$$
Then for t=0
$$u_t(x,0)= c(g'(x)-f(x))\Leftrightarrow c(g'(x)-f'(x)) =h(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow g'(x)=f'(x) \tag 8$$

Now we differentiate $(7)$ with respect of $x$ and we get
$$f'(x)+g'(x)=\varphi'(x)=-\frac{2x}{(x^2+9)^2} \tag 9$$

From $(8)$ and $(9)$ we have
$$2f'(x)=-\frac{2x}{(x^2+9)^2}$$

So
$$\int 2 f'(x)dx=\int -\frac{2x}{(x^2+9)^2}dx \Leftrightarrow f(x)= \frac{1}{2(x^2+9)}+f_0 \Leftrightarrow f(x)= \frac{\varphi(x)}{2}+f_0\tag{10}$$
and $$g(x)=\frac{\varphi(x)}{2}+f_0 \tag{11}$$
Where $f_0$ arbitrary constant.
Then the solution to the initial condition problem is

$$u(x,t)=f(−)+g(+)=\frac{\varphi(−)}{2}+\frac{\varphi(+)}{2}$$

But it does not seem right to me. Any advice?

Comment: Why the solution "does not seem right"? It is a correct answer.

Comment: @Artem I think I have made a  wrong substitution of $\xi$ and $\eta$ in D’Alemebert’s Method

Comment: Oh, sorry, the correct answer of course $(\phi(x+ct)+\phi(x-ct))/2$